# Custom array sort ( YUYV -> YUV422P)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, image-processing, sorting

I'm trying to sort and array from YUYV format to YUV422p format. The array currently looks like:

[y1][cb1][y2][cr1][y3][cb2][y4][cr2][y5][cb3][y6][cr3][y7][cb4][y8][cr4] ...[yn][cbn+1/2][yn+1][crn+1/2]

and i need to sort it to look like:

[y1][y2][y3][y4][y5][y6][y7][y8][yn][yn+1]..[cb1][cb2][cb3][cb4][cbn+1/2]..[cr1][cr2][cr3][cr4][crn+1/2]

all the y's need to be together, all the cb's together, all the cr's together.

I'm trying to make this section as efficient as possible and take the least amount of time.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
    inline const void YUYV_to_YUV422P_1280x960( char* yuyv, char* yuv422p)
    {
         const unsigned int height = 960;
         const unsigned int width  = 1280;
         int loopCount1 = height*width/2;
         int loopCount2 = height*width;
         char* yComponent   = yuv422p;
         char* cbComponent  = yuv422p + loopCount2;
         char* crComponent  = yuv422p + loopCount1 + loopCount2; 

         int i;
         for( i = (loopCount1 - 1); i != 0; --i )
         {
           cbComponent[ i ] = yuyv[ i*4 + 1 ];
           crComponent[ i ] = yuyv[ i*4 + 3 ];
         }

         for( i = (loopCount2 -1); i != 0; --i )
         {
           yComponent[ i ] = yuyv[ i*2 ];
         }
    }
```

Any thoughts on how to make this more efficient and faster please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The advice is as always measure it and then decide if it's fast enough. If you are doing this on a 3GHz PC is saving a few microsecs going to matter?

Generally on this sort of task you are memory I/O limited, so writing it for best cache performance is important. Depending on the size of your images and the hw it might be best to process the image a row at a time so you have the input an output image rows in cache

If you have a modern CPU you can speed it up with SSE2 and do a lot of these ops on multiple pixels at the same time.